# How to use integer type in PayloadRegexDecoder of HEKA

Tags: parsing, elasticsearch, integer

I'm trying to use HEKA(instead of logstash) for log parser to insert Elasticsearch.
At this time, I use PayloadRegexDecoder to split each fields.

Most configurations are working as I expect except integer type.

**Input log string**

```
May 4 13:01:04 db1 monitoring: 2015-05-04T13:01:01Z 174.35.6.22 aaaa bbbb 111
```

**This is my sample configuration of HEKA.**

```
[fdb]
type = "PayloadRegexDecoder"
match_regex = '^(?P<month>.+?) (?P<day>.+?) (?P<time>.+?) (?P<remote_user>.+?) monitoring: (?P<Timestamp>.+?) (?P<ip>.+?) (?P<a>.+?) (?P<b>.+?) (?P<int_test>\d+)'

[fdb.message_fields]
Type = "f_monitoring"
month = "%month%"
day = "%day%"
time = "%time%"
remote_user = "%remote_user%"
ip|ipv4 = "%ip%"
a = "%a%"
b = "%b%"
int_test|B = "%int_test%"`
```

**This is the result of this setup.**

```
:Timestamp: 2015-05-04 13:01:01 +0000 UTC
:Type: f_monitoring
:Hostname: 
:Pid: 0
:Uuid: b824d53c-7d7e-4424-a123-780aa37bf879
:Logger: UdpInput
:Payload: May 4 13:01:04 db1 monitoring: 2015-05-04T13:01:01Z 174.35.6.22 aaaa bbbb 111
:EnvVersion: 
:Severity: 7
:Fields:
   | name:"int_test" type:string value:"111" representation:"B"
   | name:"a" type:string value:"aaaa"
   | name:"time" type:string value:"13:01:04"
   | name:"b" type:string value:"bbbb"
   | name:"ip" type:string value:"174.35.6.22" representation:"ipv4"
   | name:"day" type:string value:"4"
   | name:"remote_user" type:string value:"db1"
   | name:"month" type:string value:"May"
```

I'd like know how to change type of int_test from string to integer or double.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't. Looking through their source the value of a regex match will always be a string. You can change the representation, but I don't know that that will change anything.

What you could do though is add a lua decoder. I don't think you can delete a field from a message. So, you'd have to pull a copy of the message into lua, convert the field, and then send back the mutated message.

Here's the outline for the lua code (untested):

```
function process_message ()
    local mutableMessageCopy = decode_message(read_message("raw"))
    mutableMessageCopy.Fields.int_test = tonumber(mutableMessageCopy.Fields.int_test)
    inject_message(msg)
    return 0
end
```

And here's what you would add to your config, if you named the lua file convertint.lua; you would also have to update your input to use "chain_fbp" instead of "fbp":

```
[chain_fbp]
type = "MultiDecoder"
subs = ['fbp', 'convert_to_integer']
cascade_strategy = "all"

[convert_to_integer]
type = "SandboxDecoder"
filename = "/absolute/path/to/the/lua/code/convertint.lua"
```